# How to show that the divergence can be written as the trace of total covariant derivative, ${\rm div}={\rm tr}\circ\nabla$?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.

> From John Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds*, the divergence operator $\text{div}:\Gamma(TM)\to C^{\infty}(M)$ is defined to be the map that sends $X$ to the unique function $\text{div} X$ such that
>   $$(\text{div} X) \,dV_g = d(X\lrcorner \,dV_g),$$
>   where $dV_g$ is the volume form and $\lrcorner$ denoted the interior multiplication.

The above seems pretty complicated to me. Recently, I have found a much more accessible definition, i.e.
$$
\text{div} = \text{tr} \circ \nabla
$$
where $\nabla$ denotes the total covariant derivative.

> How do we show that these definitions are equivalent?

It seems to me that the books I found only use either one of these and do not mention the other.

Comment: Note that Lee's definition does not require a connection or even a metric — just a volume form.

Comment: @TedShifrin: But volume form is depend on the metric.

Comment: @C.F.G Yes, but you can define a volume form without a metric if the manifold is orientable. Regardless, a connection is not required.

Comment: @TedShifrin: but div is defined for metric volume form. In that case is it well-defined?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/953960/173147

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can show that this equality holds at any point of $M$ by computing in local coordinates. At the point $p\in M$ we use Riemannian normal coordinates, which have the property that the metric at $p$ is given by the identity matrix, $g_{ij}(p)=\delta_{ij}$, and that the derivatives of the metric coefficients are zero at $p$, as are the Christoffel symbols. With this we can write
\begin{equation}
\text{tr}\ \nabla X (p) = \sum_{i=1}^n g(\nabla_{\partial_i} X,\partial_i)(p) = \sum_{i=1}^n(\partial_i X^j)(p)\delta_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n\partial_i X^i(p).
\end{equation}
On the other hand, we have $\text{det}(g)(p)=1$ in these coordinates, and since the determinant is polynomial in the entries of the matrix of $g$, all its partial derivatives vanish at $p$ in these coordinates. With $dV_g = \sqrt{|g|}dx^1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^n$ we can write
\begin{equation}
X\lrcorner\ dV_g = \sqrt{|g|}\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1}X^i dx^1\wedge\ldots\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^n,
\end{equation}
where the hatted factor is the one excluded from the wedge product. Noting that the partial derivatives of $\sqrt{|g|}$ vanish at $p$ we can write
\begin{equation}
d(X\lrcorner\ dV_g)(p) = \sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1}(\partial_j X^i)(p)dx^j\wedge dx^1\wedge\ldots\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^n.
\end{equation}
All the terms where $i\neq j$ will be zero by antisymmetry of $\wedge$. Permuting the leftmost factor $dx^j$ to the place of the hatted factor we change sign $i-1$ times, so the sign factors cancel. We are left with
\begin{equation}
d(X\lrcorner\ dV_g)(p) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n(\partial_i X^i)(p)\right)\ dx^1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^n = \text{tr}\ \nabla X(p)\ dV_g.
\end{equation}

Comment: Excuse me. Did you use the notation $|g|$ for $\det(g)$? Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

I'll add another completely different solution. If $M$ is any manifold, $\nabla$ is any torsion-free connection, $X$ is any vector field and $\beta\in \Omega^k(M)$, then $$\mathscr{L}_X\beta = \nabla_X\beta +\sum_{i=1}^k\beta(\cdot,\ldots,\nabla X,\ldots,\cdot).$$So if $\omega\in\Omega^n(M)$ is a top degree form, we have $$\mathscr{L}_X\omega = \nabla_X\omega+({\rm div}\,X)\omega$$by linear algebra. Cartan's magic formula turns that into $${\rm d}(\iota_X\omega) = \nabla_X\omega+({\rm div}\,X)\omega.$$If $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and we apply this to ${\rm d}V_g$, which is parallel (as the Ricci tensor of the Levi-Civita connection is symmetric), it follows that $${\rm d}(\iota_X{\rm d}V_g)=({\rm div}\,X){\rm d}V_g$$as wanted. So this is a more powerful proof that does not rely on local computations, and holds for metrics of any signature.

Comment: How you apply $\text{tr} \circ \nabla X$ to $\sum_{i=1}^k\omega(\cdot,\ldots,\nabla X,\ldots,\cdot)={\rm div}\,X)\omega$? it doesn't matter which index is contracting in diff-forms?

Comment: This is linear algebra: if $T:V \to V$ is a linear map and $\omega \in (V^*)^{\wedge n}$, where $n=\dim V$, then $$\sum_{k=1}^n \omega(v_1,...,Tv_k,...,v_n) = ({\rm tr}(T))\omega(v_1,...,v_n).$$To see this, differentiate $\omega(Tv_1,...,Tv_n)=(\det T)\omega(v_1,...,v_n)$ relative to $T$ using that the derivative of $\det$ at the identity is ${\rm tr}$, with the product rule (as $\omega$ is multilinear). I'm applying this fact with $T = \nabla X$.

Comment: Sorry, parallelity of volume form is straightforward, so why you remarked that Ricci tensor is symmetric?

Comment: Oh, no particular reason. This answer is old, when I got the notification and read it again I had in mind that a manifold with an arbitrary connection admits a parallel volume form iff the Ricci tensor is symmetric, you can completely ignore that remark if it confused you.

Answer (score 7):

We can work locally since everything there is a tensor. Assume $(E_1,\ldots,E_n)$ is a local orthonormal frame field, such that $(\nabla_{E_j}E_i)_p = 0$ for some $p \in M$. We will check the equality at $p$.

If $(\theta^1,\ldots, \theta^n)$ is the corresponding coframe, then $$dV_g = \theta^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \theta^n.$$We can write $X = \sum_{i=1}^n \theta^i(X) E_i$, and we also know that $\theta^i(X) = \langle X,E_i\rangle$, by orthonormality. On one hand, it is easy (?) to check that $${\rm tr}(\nabla X) = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle \nabla_{E_i}X,E_i\rangle,$$so let's compute the other expression. We start computing the interior derivative $$\begin{align}\iota_X(dV_g) &= \iota_X(\theta^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \theta^n) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} \theta^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \iota_X(\theta^i)\wedge \cdots \wedge \theta^n \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} \theta^i(X) \;\theta^1\wedge \cdots \wedge\widehat{\theta^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge \theta^n, \end{align}$$where the hat denotes omission. Then we compute the exterior derivative of that: $$\begin{align} d(\iota_X(dV_g)) &= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} E_j(\theta^i(X)) \; \theta^j \wedge \theta^1\wedge \cdots \wedge\widehat{\theta^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge \theta^n \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} E_i(\theta^i(X)) \;\theta^i\wedge \theta^1\wedge \cdots \wedge\widehat{\theta^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge \theta^n 
 \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n E_i(\theta^i(X)) \;\theta^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \theta^n \\ &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n E_i(\theta^i(X))\right) \theta^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \theta^n \\ &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n E_i(\theta^i(X))\right) dV_g.\end{align}$$The result follows since at $p$ we have $$(E_i)_p(\theta^i(X)) = \langle (\nabla_{E_i}X)_p,(E_i)_p\rangle + \langle X, (\nabla_{E_i}E_i)_p\rangle =\langle (\nabla_{E_i}X)_p,(E_i)_p\rangle. $$The result is also true for pseudo-Riemannian manifolds, with a slight adaptation of the calculations done above.