# Confusion about connection, covariant derivative and definition of divergence of a vector in terms of covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Let $V \in T_p M$ be a vector at the point $p$ in a manifold $M$. The connection $\nabla$ is defined such that $\nabla V$ is a $(1,1)$ tensor:
\begin{align*}
\nabla V: T_p M \rightarrow T_p M \otimes T_p^*M .
\end{align*}
If $X$ be another vector at $p$ then we define the covariant derivative of $V$ in the direction of $X$ as,
\begin{align*}
\nabla_X V: T_p M \otimes T_p M \rightarrow T_p M.
\end{align*}
Thus, $\nabla_X V$ is a $(1,0)$ tensor. We also write,
\begin{align}
(\nabla V) (X) = \nabla_X V \qquad \qquad (1)
\end{align}
However, this is also written as,
\begin{align}
\nabla_X V = X \cdot \nabla V = X^a \nabla_{e_a} V \qquad (2)
\end{align} 
where ${e_a}$ is a set of basis vectors. I do not understand the meaning of the last expression in eq. 2.
I also have a confusion about what is denoted by the symbol $\nabla$. By itself, as far as I understand, $\nabla$ is not a $(0,1)$ tensor i.e. $\nabla \neq \nabla_a e^a$ (where ${e^a}$ forms a set of basis co vectors) but acting on a vector or, in general, a tensor of rank $(p,q)$ it yields a tensor of rank $(p,q+1)$. Am I correct?

Now, how do we define $Div V$? I read in the post [Divergence in terms of Levi-Civita connection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953960/divergence-in-terms-of-levi-civita-connection) that
\begin{align*}
Div V = trace(\nabla V).
\end{align*}
To take the trace, I need to write $\nabla V$ as $\nabla_a V^b$, may be in abstract index notation. But I do not understand why we can put the covariant index $a$ on $\nabla$.

P.S.: I am not a mathematician and am trying to learn writing precisely. So, if there are mistakes in my notations, please do point them out.

Comment: What's your definition of connection on $TM$?  Mine is an operator $\nabla:\mathfrak{X}(M)\times\mathfrak{X}(M)\to\mathfrak{X}(M)$ that is (a.) $C^\infty$-linear in the "bottom" variable, (b.) $\mathbb{R}$-linear in the "top" variable, and then (c.) satisfies the Leibniz rule for the "top" variable.  So you're Eq.(2) is just the (a.) part of the definition.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by the symbol $\mathcal X(M)$. (How do you write the symbol that you used?) In my first unnumbered equation, I defined the connection as an operator that acting on a vector $V$ gives a $(1,1)$ tensor $\nabla V$. Similarly, in the second unnumbered equation, given two vectors $X,V$ we get a $(1,0)$ tensor $\nabla_X V$ which is the covariant derivative of $V$ in the direction of $X$.

Comment: \mathfrak{X} gives you your fraktur font (typically used for Lie algebras, and hence why used here) and is common notation to denote the space of vector fields, or sections of the tangent bundle (another common notation would be $\Gamma(TM)$).  As to the question, you gave no definition for $\nabla$, you said "$\nabla V$ is defined such a way:", so I'm asking what is the way it's defined?  I think one thing of confusion, is that $\nabla$ isn't meant to act on tangent vectors, it's meant to act on vector fields (it turns out to be okay in the bottom variable).

Comment: I highly suggest taking a look at Lee's "Riemannian Manifolds" text, chapter 4 on Connections to see how such can be explicitly defined.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. Yes, I understand that $\nabla$ is supposed to act on vector fields because the connection is necessary to compare vector fields at two points in a manifold. However, why is it okay in the bottom variable? May be, I should go through the book before asking further questions.

Comment: Given $X,Y\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$, we have $\nabla_X Y$ as a new vector fields as I defined in the top comment.  It turns out (through proof), that $(\nabla_XY)_p$ depends on only $X_p$ and $Y$ in a neighborhood of $p$.  That both are local should make some sense, as it's a differential operator.  That it turns out to depend only on the tangent vector $X_p$ it due to the fact that $C^\infty(M)$-linear in that variable (so you need only check that $(\nabla_XY)_p=0$ for any $X$ such that $X_p=0$..

Comment: I can see the first part of your comment but do not understand the last sentence "That it turns out to depend ...". I am not conversant about vector bundles and their sections.